# How to determine which variable controls indentation offset for any given mode

Tags: indentation

Each major mode seems to (quite unfortunately) have its own naming conventions for the special variable used to control indentation level.  For example, `c-mode` has `c-basic-offset`, `python-mode` has `python-indent-offset`, `perl-mode` has `cperl-indent-level`.

How can I determine which variable I should set for any given mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some common patterns (you've already noted that "offset" and "indent" are likely terms), but ultimately each mode is free to implement indentation however it likes using any arbitrary variable name(s) it wants to use, so there is no guaranteed way to determine this information.

Furthermore a derived mode might rely entirely on its parent mode for indentation, and consequently the variable(s) in question may not even have the name prefix you expect.

My best advice is check the `customize-group` interface for the library in question, or to use `apropos-variable` with the pattern `offset\|indent`, and if that fails, be sure to check the parent mode (if any; use `describe-function` or `find-function`) so that you can chase up the same things in that mode (or indeed its own parent, etc...)

There's also SMIE, which is the nearest thing to a "standard" approach to indentation in Emacs that I know of, but which is *relatively* new and so presumably unlikely to have been adopted by very many pre-existing modes. I don't know too much about it, but you can read about it in the manual: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) SMIE Customization` <kbd>RET</kbd>